# Match a character to regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to duplicate all consonants characters in a String. As an example:

```
Hello, how do you do?
```

would become:

```
HHellllo, hhoww ddo yyouu ddo?
```

So far here's what I've came up with.

```
char[] charArray = "Hello, how do you do?".toCharArray();
String pattern = "[BbCcDdFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpQqRrSsTtVvWwXxZz]";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for(char c : charArray){
   String theChar = "" + c;
   if(theChar.matches(pattern)){
       sb.append(c);
   }
   sb.append(c);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

It works but I'm sure there's a better way to use regex for this. I just don't feel that it's efficient to create a String for each character each time I need to use `matches()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with your current regex and `"$0$0"` as the replacement, to duplicate all of the matches (each match will be a single character):

```
String text = "Hello, how do you do?";
String pattern = "[BbCcDdFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpQqRrSsTtVvWwXxZz]";
String result = text.replaceAll(pattern, "$0$0");
System.out.println(result);
```

In the replacement string `$0` is a reference to the entire match, if you have capturing groups you can use `$1`, `$2`, and so on to refer to the associated capturing group.  The following page has some additional info on using regular expressions in Java:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Note that you can also shorten your regex a bit, Casimir's answer has a nice approach, here is another:

```
String pattern = "(?i)(?![aeiou])[a-z]";
```

This works because `(?![aeiou])` is a negative lookahead that means "fail if the next character is a vowel", so even though `[a-z]` will match any lowercase character including vowels this regex will still only match consonants.  The `(?i)` at the beginning make the regex case insensitive.

Comment: It would also benefit , how the $0$0 works. To me this is magic. Any document / reference would help . Will this behavior works in all language ?

Comment: I like to use cheat sheets for regex as I cannot memorize them or use context clues to figure them out.  http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: @F.J  Thanks for the link. I have visited that size lot of time , never caught in my eyes :)

Comment: It works nicely. I want the second character to be always be in lowercase and $0\L$0 doesn't work (Invalid escape sequence). Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `replaceAll`, you would need to iterate over the matches.  In the link from my question towards the bottom of the "Using The Matcher Class" section there is a piece of code that might be a good starting point, using the `appendReplacement` method of the matcher.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a class intersection

```
String result = text.replaceAll("(?i)[b-z&&[^eiouy]]" , "$0$0");
```

Comment: Minor detail, but the original code seems to consider `y` a vowel as well.

Answer (score 1):

`String` class has a builtin method, `replaceAll()`, for just such an occasion.

```
String sb = input.replaceAll("([BbCcDd...])", "$1$1");
```

The `$1` means "whatever was in the parentheses in the pattern".